# Application facebook - Passing a parameter into the url delet the facebook $session?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

heres my problem.

the index.php file
Code:

```
    <?php

    require_once ('../src/facebook.php');
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true,
      ));
      $session = $facebook->getSession();
      print_r($session);
       ?>
```

It works fine, i do have all the $session information.

But as soon as i call index.php?param=x, i dont have anymore my session information.

How come?

Comment: is there any parameter specifically that causes this behaviour or is it for every parameter you send?

Comment: where are you developing? facebook connect site? iframe canvas? or iframe page tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked inside facebook.php, when you're using *OAuth 2.0* that uses **signed_request**, it is the first source where it gets the session.

signed_request is passed to you using *POST for canvas* if it is enabled in advanced settings.

When you navigate to other pages using GET method like **index.php?param=x**, you lose the signed_request.

We had this problem before and opted to use AJAX inside our iframe to retain the signed_request in index.php and the ajax-loaded pages will generate cookie-based session because they don't have signed_request.

If you want, you can also disable *OAuth 2.0* in advanced settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i do disable OAuth 2.0, I will just lose the parameters of &session too. So the only way is to use AJAX and remainin the same page without redirecting? Is there anything more simplier? I don't want todeploy the whole AJAX librairy in fact.

Comment: then you might wanna store the signed_request on a session variable. refetch it on the next page which is ?param=x.

Comment: @dragonjet, can you please descibe where to allow the signed request in the application advanced settings??